# in Debian 12, KDE, Network Manager doesn't show/rcognize wireless connection

Tags: debian, kde, networkmanager

Wireless internet is working, but wireless connections doen't appear in settings and are not recognize by the NetworkManager.

1. in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
allow-hotplug wlp13s0
iface wlp13s0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid <network_name>
        wpa-psk  <network_pass>
```

Setting `managed=true` and restarting the service, will stop the internet connection and
still not recognized.

2. `nmcli dev set wlp13s0 managed yes` is not working

```
wlp13s0: unmanaged
        "MEDIATEK MT7921K 6E 80MHz"
        wifi (mt7921e), 10:6F:D9:DC:12:5F, hw, mtu 1500
```

Obs. kernel is 6.4 from backports

```
modinfo mt7921e
filename:       /lib/modules/6.4.0-0.deb12.2-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mediatek/mt76/mt7921/mt7921e.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
author:         Lorenzo Bianconi <lorenzo@kernel.org>
author:         Sean Wang <sean.wang@mediatek.com>
firmware:       mediatek/WIFI_MT7922_patch_mcu_1_1_hdr.bin
firmware:       mediatek/WIFI_RAM_CODE_MT7922_1.bin
firmware:       mediatek/WIFI_MT7961_patch_mcu_1_2_hdr.bin
firmware:       mediatek/WIFI_RAM_CODE_MT7961_1.bin
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00000616sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00000608sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00007922sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000014C3d00007961sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        mt76-connac-lib,mt7921-common,mt76
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mt7921e
vermagic:       6.4.0-0.deb12.2-amd64 SMP preempt mod_unload modversions
```

3. I added  `110-globally-managed-devices.conf`,empty or with `managed=false` or `managed_devices=none' and other combinations service NetworkManager fails to restart

Comment: comment out/remove the `wlp13s0` stuff from `/etc/network/interfaces` - then you can manage it through network manager